# Calling a vbscript funciton to update a SQL table from an HTML form generated on an asp-classic page

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

Having a hard time with updating a SQL table from an HTML form generated on an asp-classic page. The page dynamically creates a table based on a SQL query; I've added a form for the purpose of editing certain fields displayed in the table but have been unable to trigger the function (i.e. onclick) that the form button calls using the code below. I've tried multiple variations of the syntax used for calling the function via VBscript and am missing something entirely. I'm wondering if I'm trying something that can't be done in the asp-classic environment due to the server side code being used and the limitations that go with that (as well as my trying to use the same page to generate the results). I know the default behavior for the form is to refresh the page if I don't specify a different page. In the code below, I'm just trying to confirm the behavior before I add the SQL update statement to the function. (I'm typically only retrieving or inserting data for a web site - very little experience updating the data between a single page like this.)

```
<br>
<form method="POST" id="form" action="">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="state">
<%
'populate the dropdown selection for the state within the form
do until rs.eof
   For each x in rs.fields
      response.write "<option value=" & x.Value & ">" & x.Value & "</option>" & vbNewLine
   next
   rs.movenext
loop
%>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="ps">
                <option value="blank"></option>
                <option value="prime">Primary</option>
                <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="emp_num" size="5" maxlength="5" rows="1" ></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" onclick="Go" value="Update record"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<%
function Go() {

msgbox "test" 
//additional SQL code would be included here once the function actually works
}
%>

<%
'close the DB connection
dbconn.close 
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you can't call server side code (function go) from client side code (onlcikc) like that.  What you usually do is Submit the form, so as to call the page again or another page, that then gets the fields submitted and does the SQL work and then serves up to the user the updated data or status of the submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mix server-side code with client-side code, and It Don't Work Like That<sup>TM</sup>.

Here's a very rough outline of how you could get information from the user, process it, and display it, all on the same asp page. Note the utter lack of JavaScript. :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylestuff.css">
<%
Dim rs, sql, conn
Dim mylist, myval1, myval2, i

myval1 = Request.Form("val1")
myval2 = Request.Form("val2")
'- If the form hasn't been submitted yet, myval1&2 will be the special value Empty, 
'- but you can treat them as a blank string ("") for all intents and purposes.
If Validate(myval1, myval2) = True and myval1 & myval2 <> "" Then
    DoStuffWith myval1, myval2
End If
%>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Page</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Select one: <select name="val1" size="1">
    <%
    ListStuff mylist
    For i = 0 to UBound(mylist,1)
        response.write "<option value='" & mylist(0,i) & "'"
        If myval & "" = mylist(0,i) & "" Then response.write " selected"
        response.write ">" & mylist(1,i) & "</option>"
    Next
    %>
    </select></p>
<p>Write something here: 
    <input type="text" name="val2" value="<%=myval2%>" size="10"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
<%
If myval1 & myval2 <> "" Then
    DisplayStuff myval1, myval2
End If
%>
</body>
</html>
<%
Sub ListStuff(L)
    sql = "Select [...] From [...] Where [...]"
    Set rs = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open sql, "connection string (or previously-opened connection object)", 1,2
    If Not rs.EOF Then 
        L = rs.GetRows
    Else
        Redim L(1,0)
        L(0,0) = 0 : L(1,0) = "missing!"
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
'---------------------------------
Function Validate(v1,v2)
dim f
    f = True
    If Not Isnumeric(v1) Then f = False
    If Len(v2) > 10 Then f = False
    Validate = f
End Function
'---------------------------------
Sub DoStuffWith(v1,v2)
    '- table-creation (or whatever) code goes here
End Sub
'---------------------------------
Sub DisplayStuff(v1,v2)
    '- display code goes here
End Sub
%>
```

Comment: Okay, I think I'm following the logic. Everything runs on the initial page render and only a "pre-populated" form would get processed when it loads. I have 3 values on the form though. Shouldn't I pass all three values to

Comment: the subroutine (i.e more than just myval to the Sub DoStuffWith)? I'm accustomed to seeing an argument in parentheses for that type of function (where you can pass multiple arguments by simply separating with commas); in trying that with your subroutine, I get errors. Everything I've seen using a web search uses the parentheses structure.

Comment: To pass multiple values to a subroutine, you *do* just separate them with commas: `dim myval1, myval2` ... `DisplayStuff myval1, myval2` ... `Sub DisplayStuff(v1,v2)`. For a function, the calling syntax changes slightly: `If Validate(myval1, myval2) Then` (note the parentheses). If you have lots of fields on the form (say, a dozen or more), then you can just use global variables: `dim myval1, myval2` ... `DisplayStuff` ... `Sub DisplayStuff()` (and then rewrite the subs to use `myval1`, not `v1`).

Comment: @KRussell: note that you can't format (e.g. bold/italic) text that's in a code block. But I went ahead and added a second parameter to the sample code, just so it's easier to see how the syntax works. You should have no problem extending that to however many actual fields/parameters you need in your real code.

Comment: Thanks! Your advice got me through this. Really appreciate the help.